# Confused with the time diagram and wiring for this SSI interface

Tags: encoder

I have an [AEAT-6010/6012 10/12-bit magnetic absolute encoder](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0e8d/0900766b80e8dd0c.pdf) and it has the following pin-outs:

[image]

Since it is SSI but not SPI I dont use the CSn output and leave it.

I supply 5V to the encoder and clock it between 60kHz up to 100kHz but I dont get any expected data at DO pin. When I observe DO by a scope it is just a very low level clock signal but not any data stream expected.

At one page it is mentioned that CSn is internal pull-up:
[image]

And unlike for a typical SSI this encoder also has a timing diagram for CSn:

[image]

When I measure CSn, it seems it is always 5V. Am I doing wrong by not using CSn here? Where and how should the CSn pin be connected? I'm really confused the interfacing of this pin and the function of it.

Comment: Should I apply 5VDC to CSn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing wrong by not using CSn here?

Yes, you are wrong by not using CSn. It is clear from the datasheet that this signal is *required* and must be driven low, with the timing shown in the diagram you supplied from the datasheet.

> Where and how should the CSn pin be connected?

It would be driven by the same device (MCU?) which is driving the CLK signal (unless you are doing something *very* unusual).

Comment: Thanks yes I use the same MCU. But For CS to be driven LOW I need to connect CS to Vdd i.e. 5V isnt it?

Comment: @atmnt - "*I need to connect CS to Vdd i.e. 5V isnt it?*" Due to the pull-up built into the sensor, no. The exact details will depend on your *specific* MCU and its GPIO voltage limits and configuration. You need to drive CSn *low* when required. It has a pull-up to the encoder's power supply (5V). I would configure an open-drain output on the MCU to drive CSn low - assuming your MCU's GPIO is 5V-tolerant. Also note that you must meet the timing requirements in the datasheet (Table 4 and Figure 2), when driving CSn and CLK.

Comment: I am guessing timing requirements doesnt matter(Im not sure) It seems it is to enable one of the multiple encoders. But I can try. My MCU at the moment is ATEMGA328P at the moment Im using the ArduinoNano board. I tried to connect CS to Vdd it didnt work. Can you link or make a small diagram how I can drive that CS down forever?

Comment: Or should I just ground that pin ? I first want to try to drive down forever to test. Maybe timing is not necessary for a single encoder,

Comment: @atmnt - "*I am guessing timing requirements doesnt matter(Im not sure)*" No, it really *does* matter! "*I tried to connect CS to Vdd it didnt work.*" Yes, that will never work :-( Vdd = high, not low. "*Or should I just ground that pin ?*" That won't work after the first readout. "*Can you link or make a small diagram how I can drive that CS down forever?*" Won't work. **Follow the datasheet.** I don't know your experience, but have you used SPI before? Do you understand the difference between open-drain and push-pull outputs? How many SPI devices have you successfully interfaced before?

Comment: I used only one time SPI programmable poti. Okay now I will change my code for master then. I was not sure whether I should directly connect this CS to the one of the MCU(Nano) output pin(which will be ON OFF). ATMEGA328P is not open drain so can I just wire the CS to one of the digital pin to control enable? This open drain and push pull I read about them but when it comes to implement I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Is your ATMETA328P powered from the same 5V supply as the encoder? If so, you can drive CSn with a push-pull output. Or you could just add an external transistor & resistor to convert the push-pull MCU output to an open-drain output (with a MOSFET) or open-collector output (with BJT).

Comment: Yes exactly same supply. Now I directly coupled CS to pin 4 which goes off and and on during data stream similar to the datasheet. I get data stream now. I just need to tweak it a bit(there is RC decay at the end of each datastream). Maybe I should add some scope screen shots later.

Comment: "*I get data stream now.*" Great - problem solved :-) "*there is RC decay at the end of each datastream*" Look at the datasheet. The DO signal goes tristate at the end of each position data output. I would probably add a pull-up resistor on DO.

Comment: Pull up or pull down? But the DO is input to the micro controller. It is not something like this https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/6/f/b/c/7/511568b6ce395f1b40000000.jpg DO is either 5V or 0V data stream.

Comment: 1k pull down from DO to GND solved the issue